# Is ActionContext in Struts 2 unique to the current request?

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, thread-local, actioncontext

I'm using a custom interceptor which creates a new db connection, and sets this connection onto the current action before executing the action. After that, the interceptor closes the connection.

I'm looking for a convenient way to share this db connection with other classes / static methods (such as Models) that are used by the action. E.g so I can call static method like `User.get( id )` or `User.getEmail( id )` without having to pass the db connection to each method separately.

I could set the db connection onto the `ActionContext` from the interceptor, by doing:

`ServletActionContext.getActionContext().put("db", db );`

And then I could access this db connection from a static method, such as:

```
public class User implements Model
{ 
   public static String getEmail(int id)
   {
      Connection db = 
         (Connection) ServletActionContext.getActionContext().get("db");
      //...
   }
}
```

My question is, would a new `ActionContext` be generated for every given request, so I can be sure that a new db connection will be used each time? E.g if I have 500 people visiting `mysite.com/fooAction`, could I be sure that each of those 500 requests is generating a unique ActionContext, and each call to `User.getEmail()` would access only the db connection which is unique to the given request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, would a new ActionContext be generated for every given
>   request, so I can be sure that a new db connection will be used each
>   time?

Since ActionContext uses ThreadLocal it is thread safe. Struts 2 creates an ActionContext for each request, and each request has its own thread. So yes, if you create a new connection and store it in the ActionContext every thread will have its own connection. But I don't recommend you to store the connection in the ActionContext because this couple you to Struts 2 which is not a good thing, also your services shouldn't be calling web specific classes because it also couple them.

[From Struts 2 Javadoc:](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.html)

> The ActionContext is the context in which an Action is executed. Each
>   context is basically a container of objects an action needs for
>   execution like the session, parameters, locale, etc.
>
> The ActionContext is thread local which means that values stored in
>   the ActionContext are unique per thread. See the
>   ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal class for more information. The
>   benefit of this is you don't need to worry about a user specific
>   action context, you just get it:
>
> ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext(); Finally, because
>   of the thread local usage you don't need to worry about making your
>   actions thread safe.

**ActionContext** excerpt:

```
public class ActionContext implements Serializable {

    static ThreadLocal<ActionContext> actionContext = new ThreadLocal<ActionContext>();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Question.. if in the beginning of my class, I had the following line: `private static Connection db =(Connection)ServletActionContext.getActionContext().get("db");`, will this be executed as thread local too, or will it be better to get the db within each method individually?

Comment: @ClickUpvote that wouldn't be thread local. It also would give you a NullPointerException because static is called as soon as the class loader loads the class and at that time Struts 2 hasn't even initialized and there is no request either. So you should call it inside the method.

Comment: Thanks man.. really appreciate your help. This is one of those issues that can have you stumped for a long time, or you think there's no solution.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question :

> My question is, would a new ActionContext be generated for every given
>   request, so I can be sure that a new db connection will be used each
>   time?

Is yes. Reference is the [java-doc](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.html). It similar to the one provided by [Alfredo Osorio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410946/alfredo-osorio) only it refers to 2.3.x version.

Can you say what struts2 version is being used?

I was not able to find any version that uses

```
ServletActionContext.getActionContext()
```

but instead the signature is

```
ServletActionContext.getActionContext(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

To answer the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437095/is-actioncontext-in-struts-2-unique-to-the-current-request#comment29350591_19437284) regarding thread-local being static and still the ActionContext instance being unique per request its because the doing a

```
ActionContext.getContext()
```

internally invokes a get on the thread local instance.

```
 actionContext.get()
```

You may find the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784009/why-should-java-threadlocal-variables-be-static) helpful in this regard.

However to delve deeper, the method

```
ServletActionContext.getActionContext(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

takes a different route than using the thread-local.

```
public static ActionContext getActionContext(HttpServletRequest req) {
    ValueStack vs = getValueStack(req);
    if (vs != null) {
        return new ActionContext(vs.getContext());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static ValueStack getValueStack(HttpServletRequest req) {
    return (ValueStack) req.getAttribute(STRUTS_VALUESTACK_KEY);
}
```

[getActionContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.15/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.java#ServletActionContext.getActionContext%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29)

[getValueStack](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.15/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.java#ServletActionContext.getValueStack%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29)

Below are some additional references (source code).

[ValueStack](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ValueStack.java#ValueStack.getContext%28%29)

[OgnlValueStack](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ognl/OgnlValueStack.java#OgnlValueStack.getContext%28%29)

[ActionContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.java)

The following posts may also be helpful.

1. [will-a-new-actioncontext-and-valuestack-be-created-for-every-new-action-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545166/will-a-new-actioncontext-and-valuestack-be-created-for-every-new-action-object)
2. [struts2-actioncontext-and-valuestack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296108/struts2-actioncontext-and-valuestack)

Update 2 :

Wanted to add as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546630/2862341) (Link 1 above) that in case of [ActionChaining](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/action-chaining.html) being involved, the action is invoked with its own interceptor stack and result.

The thread in which its executed, however is the same.

The value-stack and parameters are copied over. See - ActionChainResult#execute(ActionInvocation).

Once the chain-invocation is complete, the state of the action-context is reset. (See DefaultActionProxy#execute() ).

**Partial Information** : Although the action-invocation is set in DefaultActionInvocation#init(ActionProxy) I was not able to determine if or where it is reset.

Sources :

[DefaultActionInvocation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/DefaultActionInvocation.java)

[DefaultActionProxy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/DefaultActionProxy.java)

[DefaultActionProxyFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/DefaultActionProxyFactory.java)

[ActionChainResult](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionChainResult.java)

[FilterDispatcher(Deprecated)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.15/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.java#FilterDispatcher.doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,javax.servlet.ServletResponse,javax.servlet.FilterChain%29)

Comment: The signature which I'm using is `ServletActionContext.getContext()`, I don't have to pass in the HttpServletRequest. I'm using the latest version ( 2.3.15.2 ). Any ideas?

Comment: And if you could give any help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755939/struts-2-resetting-action-instance-while-its-still-in-interceptor that'd be great too

Comment: @ClickUpvote The method `ServletActionContext.getContext()` is actually from ActionContext. See [ActionContext.getContext()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.java#ActionContext.getContext%28%29). That invokes `actionContext.get()` as mentioned above, where `actionContext` is a ThreadLocal variable. This method is different from the method signature in the question. Perhaps you could update your question accordingly.

Comment: In either case, will the answer be the same, i.e whenever I do `ServletActionContext.getContext()`, it will be unique to each request?

Comment: Short answer is yes. Will have to get back regarding how exactly.

Comment: That's fine. Are you able to answer my other question?

Comment: @ClickUpvote - I updated the answer to include ActionChaining. Regarding the other question, (19755939), I cannot think of any reason how that could be. Will update that answer if I find anything.